# Regex: cut optional right side

Tags: regex, pcre

I need to cut standalone numbers from log file. E.g. remove everything from right side starting with 1 space + 1 number.

```
"process: 123" => text = "process:"
```

Following regex does the work:

```
^(?P<text>.*)\s\d
```

However if there is no space + number, my regex returns nothing. How can I extend my solution to satisfy following 3 requirements?

```
"process: 123" => text = "process:"
"node4" => text = "node4"
"text without number" => text = "text without number"
```

Comment: Remove what  `\s+\d.*` pattern matches. Or use an inefficient `^(?<text>.*?)(?:\s+\d.*)?$`

Comment: What language / regex engine are you using?